# In React Bootstrap, I want to format my text with html but can't

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app, react-bootstrap

In my app, I am constructing a string:

```
tempString += "\n<b>" + dResult[y].dp5 + "</b>";
```

I'm able to convert my `\n` to a `<p>` using the split below, but how can I format my text with styles, such as the `<b>`:

```
  let newText = randString.split('\n').map((item, i) => {
    return <p key={i}>{item}</p>;
  });
```

On my screen, my output is: `<b>Text</b>`, instead of actually bolding the text.

Comment: Side note: when formatting `inline code` in Markdown, use single backticks, not triple backticks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To render to HTML, stick with JSX and passing around rendered components rather than strings. You can pass an Array as a child to a React component, so keep an Array of components rather than a string:

```js
const tempComp = [];
tempComp.push(<b>{dResult[y].dp5}</b>);
```

and then render it is a child:

```js
<>
  {tempComp}
</>
```

Comment: Using .push is what ultimately helped me.  Instead of appending to each string, I used .push to create the array.

Answer (score 1):

```js
  
    // Example class component
    function BoldedComponent() {
      const strings = ['hello', 'world', 'john doe was here'];
      const tempComp = strings.map(item => (<b>{item}</b>));
      const noBoldComp = strings.map(item => (<p>{item}</p>));
      return (
        <div>
          {tempComp}
          {noBoldComp}
        </div>
      );
    }

    // Render it
    ReactDOM.render(
      <BoldedComponent />,
      document.getElementById("react")
    );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Why not constructing your `tempString` as an array of strings so you don't have to use `split()` method and can still achieve this?

```
const tempString = [];
...
tempString.push(dResult[y].dp5);
...
...
let newText = tempString.map((item, i) => {
  return <b key={i}>{item}</b>;
});
```

Or even better by constructing your `tempString` as an array of react components:

```
const tempComp= [];
...
tempComp.push(<b key={i}>{dResult[y].dp5}</b>);
...
...
<>
 {tempComp}
<>
```

Comment: The problem is that not every item is getting bolded.  Only certain ones in the list are.

Comment: I used .push, that way as the html format changes based on condition, I can push that into the array.